# Delete identity value using IDENT_CURRENT()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
     ID INT NOT NULL identity(1,1),
     Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

I need to delete from `MyTable` two records: first one with last identity value in the `MyTable` and second one with last identity value in the current session.

**To clarify:** it must be done using `IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable')`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or maybe `@@IDENTITY`.

Please help with your suggestions.

Comment: I tried multiple queries 
F.e: 
   { with cte as 
    (select id from MyTable 
    where id = ident_current('Mytable')) 
    delete from cte}
but i can't understand how delete last value in the current session after removal of id = ident_current('Mytable'),because @@identity and scope_identity returned value = ident_current('Mytable')

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and `@@IDENTITY` may provide values for `MyTable` or some other table. (`@@IDENTITY` is particularly fun where triggers are involved.) `IDENT_CURRENT()` is not going to give you the value you want if the last `INSERT` was rolled back or rows have been deleted. Are you really just trying to delete the two most recently added rows (assuming that the identity column wasn't reseeded)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `@@IDENTITY` to get last identity used in the current session and 
`IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable')` to get last identity used in this table

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable'))
OR ID = @@IDENTITY
```

Read this [Article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) for more info

**EDIT1**

if you want to delete last identity value found in a table you can use `MAX()` aggregate function

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTable WHERE ID <= @@IDENTITY)
```

**Note:** `IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable')`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` AND `@@IDENTITY` are not depending on the values stored in tables

Comment: I need to delete two records. This query deleted 1 record only. How delete last identity value after this removal? if ident_current before removal = 19117, after removal the same (19117)

Comment: Why not using `MAX(ID)`?? IDENT_CURRENT store last values of identity even if it was removed

Comment: `IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable')`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` AND `@@IDENTITY` are not depending on the values stored in tables

Comment: exactly, I can use MAX(ID) or IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable')-1. 
I thought  is some kind of trick, but this problem can solved with your solution. Thank you a lot.